# Android Studio runs previous code

Tags: android, android-studio

I have deleted one row in a class and for some the Android studio still runs it.
I have tried to Rebuild and Synchronise and it doesn't help. 
Any idea for "refreshing" the code?..

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug which dates back from three days ago was just fixed I believe, and a new version of Android Studio was released [this morning Nov 11th](http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio035released), or perhaps even yesterday.

> We've just released Android Studio 0.3.5, which fixes two issues from
>   Android Studio 0.3.4:
>
> - Issue 62011: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>     Could not initialize class
>     org.gradle.internal.nativeplatform.filesystem.FileSystems$DefaultFileSystem
> - **Certain source folders were incorrectly marked as generated folders**

You'll notice, the new version now even has a **Clean** command in the build menu (this is completely new for Android Studio). I suppose this is just in case the fix doesn't take.